# How to update my static website without changing the whole content of a bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-route53

I have just started to learn the intricacies of AWS by deploying a static website in Angular4.

By following [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html) guide I was able to rent my domain, and host my website on two seperate buckets (mywebsite.com & www.mywebsite.com), hurray !

But after checking the state on my AWS usage I have noted the following:

In the billing "Top Free Tier Services by Usage":

```
            Month-to-date usage/Free Tier limit       Forecasted month-endusage/Free Tier limit

S3 - Puts   19.00% (380.00/2,000 Requests)            53.55% (1,070.91/2,000 Requests)
```

I was surprised to see this as I have started yesterday, but from my understanding PUT operations are when I add elements to a bucket.

So far to update my website **i would delete the whole content of a bucket and add my built project altogether** this may be the reason why I have used up so much Puts.

How am I supposed to update my website without having to delete / upload everything every time? And am I right about my statements above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [aws sync](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html) command, using [AWS CLI](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/), which will recursively copies new and updated files from the source directory to the destination(to S3 bucket).

Comment: Thank you very much Ashan, I will look further into this tonight.

Comment: Should I follow [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/tutorials-windows-update-and-redeploy-application.html) tutorial that uses AWS CodeDeploy?

Comment: Above example with code deploy, deploys static content to s3 bucket for archives and deployment goes to a web server in ec2. Hope its not the usecase you have.

Comment: No, I have a domain Hosted Zone set up with Route 53, a bucket with S3, so I should use `aws sync`?

Comment: Then you can use simply aws sync

Comment: It worked, thank you, but will it solve my PUT usage issue? Are my numbers normal or will sync reduce the number of additions to my bucket?